# Use new File() with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api

I am getting a File Not Found exception when I try to access any files using Android Studio.  I am able to open a text file with AssetManager but I need to open a p12 file for oAuth Authentication.  The code I'm using is taken from https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_accounts

It seems that files can't be accessed this way in Android Studio?  What is the alternative?  I am trying to display events from a public calendar so I'm not even really sure I need oAuth (I didn't for a web app).

```
GoogleCredential credential = null;
    try {
        credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(PlusScopes.PLUS_ME))
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(KEY))
                .build();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("FUCK", "cant open");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

new File(KEY) creates a file object pointing to the path KEY.  That file doesn't exist, so you have problems.  If your p12 file is in assets, you'll need to copy it to your phone's file system first and pass in the file, rather than the asset name.